# svn: Processing REPORT request response failed: Premature end of file

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, smartsvn

I am using SVN repository for more than 8 months. Since yesterday morning it started to alert me an error like "svn: Processing REPORT request response failed: Premature end of file."

I tried with both TurtoiseSVN, and SmartSVN too.

Someone please help me to fix this issue. It will be a great help

Thank you.

Prasad.

Comment: Did any of your network settings change? Added a proxy with authentication, etc.? Can you check the SVN Server log for errors?

Comment: Can you do a clean "svn checkout"?

Comment: Yeah.. I tried with all settings. It happened so suddenly.. Anyway It seems the issue with internet provider.. I am checking on that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with Internet Service Provider. I check few other internet connections. They have made some firewall updates and it was a configuration issue at their side. If you are in Sri Lanka the Internet connection I am using is Mobitel.

Thanks.
Prasad

Comment: Did you get any response to this? I am also using Mobitel and am having issues with my svnsync commands to sync up to my external repository. I do not have this issue on an SLT connection.

Comment: Hi You contact Mr. Rizwan in mobitel. He will fix it for you. Mobitel has some configuration issue. So they fix it user wise.

Comment: Do you have a phone number for him?

Comment: No. Email to m3team@Mobitel.lk mentioning your mobitel number, etc.